# Mustache.js - using partial inside an external template file

Tags: javascript, mustache, templating, partials

I'm using external template file and I want to use a partial inside the template file (.mst file inside another .mst file)

For example I have template.mst file with this code:

```
{{#comments}}
    // Here I want to use another external .mst file
{{/comments}}
```

So I careated a comment.mst file beside the template.mst file and now I'm trying to use `{{>comment}}` to call this external template file - full example:

```
{{#comments}}
    {{>comment}}
{{/comments}}
```

But it doesn't work. I tried to play with it a little bit, I tried to add the file extension `{{>comment.mst}}` and I tried to add the path `{{>temmplates/comment}}` and any pther option.

This is the code I use to load the template:

```
$.get('templates/template.mst', function(template) {
                var rendered = Mustache.render(template, postData);
                $('.inner-container').prepend(rendered);
});
```

I guess I missing something, Can someone give me an hint? Thanks!

Comment: How do you render a template? You probably have to pass a third argument to `Mustache.render()` https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/#partials

Comment: How are you loading each of your templates? Are you sure that partial is available on the page?

Comment: I added to the question the code I use to load the template.

Should I send somehow the **comment.mst** somehow? It seat at the same folder template.mst exist.